# Condition in drag and drop in html and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Code Example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8eUG1RP-T6paHY3X3lfRUVrYTA?usp=sharing)

when i drag images all images drop but my condition is that only tulips image cannot drop in drop div or when i tries to drop the tulip image then it written on the bottom of drop div that you are not able to drop this and revert back.

Comment: It would be not worse if you give team viewer :) instead of google doc share

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Please read the [tour] and [mcve].

Comment: the issue is simple, main page is default.html i need a button which change its color when i drop the tulip image

Comment: you need to include the code in the question and not have anyone fetch that from an external source, which stands to no longer exist in the future

Comment: fred i share the link of code click on the code example on the top of question

Answer (score 0):

You can give an attribute `id="tulips"` to img tag where img-src is for tulip and then write:

```
if ($("#dvDest").closest('img').attr('id').val() == "tulips")
{
    alert("Tulips are not allowed");
    return;
}
```

Comment: is it possible that if i place a button which change its color when i drop the tulip image??

Comment: where do you want to place that button?

Comment: next to drop div

Comment: when i drop the tulip image then button change its color to red and when tulip is not drop in drop div then button color is green